# transaction chaining, isolation levels and atomicity

Tags: transaction, isolation-level

I'd like to ensure that I understand correctly how the concepts of transaction chaining, transaction isolation level and atomicity relate to each other.

Here's my understanding:

1. transaction chaining (*chained* versus *unchained* transactions) is orthogonal to the four transaction isolation levels defined by the SQL standard. I.e. all eight (4×2) combinations are possible.
2. transaction chaining is simply the default setting for each database connection. It is not a constraint and it can easily be overridden. E.g. if transactions are *chained* by default then a number of statements will only be committed when a `COMMIT` is encountered. If that is not the desired behavior, simply intersperse more `COMMIT` statements. If, on the other hand, transactions are *unchained* by default then each statement is committed automatically. If that is not the desired behavior simply wrap a block of statements inside `BEGIN` / `COMMIT`.
3. unchained transactions is the same as auto-commit.
4. atomicity of individual statements is always maintained regardless of transaction chaining or isolation level.
5. atomicity of groups of statements depends on the transaction chaining mode and the `BEGIN` / `COMMIT` statements used. It is not affected by the transaction isolation level.

Comment: is this Sybase or SQL Server?  or generic?

Comment: @MaxVernon I was trying to ask a generic question if possible; if a vendor-independent answer is not possible then Sybase ASE is my immediate use case.

Comment: Sounds to me you have it correctly defined for Sybase ASE (and incidentally SQL Server) in your question.   Perhaps someone smarter will correct me.